# How to split a string while retaining the boundary characters?

Tags: javascript, regex, split, lookbehind

I'm trying to split a string in Javascript (with semi json objects) to split on the `}, {`while I want to retain the curly braces, for this I thought to use zerowidth lookback and zerowidth lookforward as [described here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

```
"{}, {a}, {c:d}".split(/(?<=}), ?(?={)/)
```

In chrome this works as expected and produces an array of three string elements with the curly braces nicely at start and end, However in Safari & Firefox this fails because lookbehind regex is not implemented is there a nice way to retain the curly braces with the split? I tried:

```
"{}, {a}, {c:d}".split(/(}), ?({)/)
```

But this splits every character.

Comment: Try: `"{}, {a}, {c:d}".split(/, *(?={)/)`

Comment: @anubhava You pattern will match `, {a}, {c:d}`, although OP's regex doesn't. [see here](https://regex101.com/r/ZyQEL8/1)

Comment: Any reason that you cannot just split on a comma?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus actually a good question. Some of the elements do have comma's `{a:2, e:'f'}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `string.split(/}, ?(?={)/)` (where `(?<=})` positive lookbehind is converted to a consuming `}`) and then append a `}` to each item in the resulting array other than the last one.

```js
var string = "{}, {a}, {c:d}";
var items = string.split(/}, ?(?={)/);
var result = items.map(function(x,id,arr) {
  return x + (id != arr.length - 1 ? "}" : ""); 
});
console.log(result);
```